# Using reference operator when using a constant pointer to a character vs normal initialization in C

Tags: c, pointers, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p = 'c'; 
    char *q;
    char a = 'd' ;
    q = &a;
    printf("%c\n",*q);
    printf("%c\n",p);
    printf("%c\n",q);
    printf("%d\n",q);
    printf("%c\n",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> d
>   c
>   �
>   881895631 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This first, third and fourth `printfs` output is as expected, but can someone explain why a character pointer need not be dereferenced (like in the second `printf` statement). Without using dereference operator it gave the output. But when I try to use a reference operator to the pointer `p`, it gives a segmentation error. Plese explain.

Comment: Lots of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are initializing a pointer with an int value, that is 'c'. Your compiler should yield a warning for this.

So your pointer contains acctually the value 67 which is an address you certainly cannot access. So if you dereference this pointer yo try to read the char stored at the address 67 which will most of the time crash your program, because this address has never been allocated to your program.

```
printf("%c\n",*q);  // ok
printf("%c\n",p);   // undefined behaviour: %c is for printing chars
                    // but as p contains 67 (ASCII value of 'C') ends up printing c
printf("%c\n",q);   // undefined behaviour: %c is for printing chars
printf("%d\n",q);   // undefined behaviour: %d is for printing chars and not pointers
printf("%c\n",*p);  // undefined hahaviour (mostly crashes), see explanation above
```